# How can I delete folders from my trash which contain lock icon as well as some uneditable files?

Tags: 16.04, gnome, bash, lock

I just remove some folders which containing a lock sign on it by using "sudo nautilus" command from my gnome-bash terminal,But It can not allow me to remove those files from my trash menu.What Do I do?

Comment: You shoudln't have used `sudo nautilus` but `gksudo nautilus`. What happens when you run `rm -r ~/.local/share/Trash/files && mkdir ~/.local/share/Trash/files` ?

Comment: You can read about Trash here http://askubuntu.com/questions/27176/how-does-the-trash-can-work-and-where-can-i-find-official-documentation-refere?rq=1

Comment: ~$ rm -r ~/.local/share/Trash/files && mkdir ~/.local/share/Trash/files
rm: descend into write-protected directory '/home/baponkar/.local/share/Trash/files/1'? 
rm: descend into write-protected directory '/home/baponkar/.local/share/Trash/files/http.chess.android'? 
rm: descend into write-protected directory '/home/baponkar/.local/share/Trash/files/com.supercell.clashofclans.android'? 
rm: descend into write-protected directory '/home/baponkar/.local/share/Trash/files/com.whatsapp.android'? 
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/home/baponkar/.local/share/Trash/files’: File exists

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by a mistake (e.g. running `sudo nautilus`) you moved files into Trash as root you can delete the `Trash` folder by running the following command (with `root` *super-user* rights):

```
sudo rm -rf ~/.local/share/Trash/
```

The `Trash` folder will be created again in the next time you will move files into `Trash` (hopefully, this time you'll execute nautilus as regular user)